# Eclipse : Cannot generate a serial version ID

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an issue with Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) :

Anytime I want to generate a serial version ID (`serialVersionUID`) for a class that extends a `serializable` class, I get the following message :

> The following error occured : Could not find class file. Make sure the
>   file is compilable.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think eclipse is unable to compile your class file there by unable to generate the serialversionUID. check any java related build errors exists!..

Comment: Do you have this issue with aspectj ?

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I've solved this problem by the following way:

Right click the project, "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path" -> "Source" tab, remove paths tagged "missing".

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes a tool (AspectJ - AJDT for instance or another) removes the Java Nature of the project, and it doesn't compile while it doesn't show any error on the editor.

Check that you have a .project file that contains both entries : 
**org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder** and **org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Myproject</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
            <!-- This one is required -->
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>

        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>

            <!-- This one is required too -->
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: I'm going to increment the number each time this answear helps me: 2

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug issiue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=259506

Aside of modifing .project file as Marc has stated, Andrew Eisenberg suggested to try closing and openiong project again.

Using both helped in my case.

**EDIT:**
Some time ago I moved to eclipse with integrated AspectJ Development Tools. Since then I have avaiable options for aspectJ which work every time.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have any build problems( errors ), eclipse will give

```
   Could not find class file. Make sure the file is compilable.
```

error. Make sure their are no problems with your build path(like... Missisng class folders/jars ).

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse use the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder`-Builder to locate the `.class`-Files. But either the Builder did not start or did not found the `.class`-files.

Reduce the `.project`-File to

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>yourprojectsname</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Remove all of maven's build-path entries.

Add the Maven nature.

Thats all.

Answer (score 1):

In my case also I used ,

Right click the project, "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path" -> "Source" tab, remove paths tagged "missing".
Though I am not sure will it impact the project dependencies on any thing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This has worked for me:

1. Go to tab Navigator:   Window > Show View > Navigator
2. Right Click on Project
3. Build Project

Try generate serial version ID again

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

`Window > Show View > Other..`

Select:

`General > Problems`

You can see all the Eclipse problems which include jar dependencies. My issue was that I was missing a required jar file. Once I added that jar file, the issue got fixed.

Comment: that really helped to locate the exact problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if auto build is on.
The class file is required to generate serial version UID. If not build the project and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had multiple projects in my eclipse workspace. The solution is to first fix all your current project's errors, then go to "Problems" view and either fix or delete all Errors there.

Now if you re-execute the eclipse quickfix "Add generated serial version ID" it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (I'm using Maven), I had to delete one of the dependencies in the local repository because it had become corrupted. Look for errors about problem reading dependency jars.