# How do I generate the serial version UID of a Java file from command line?

Tags: java, linux, serialversionuid

## Background

I am attempting to generate the serialVersionUID of my java files in eclipse but get the error described in [Eclipse : Cannot generate a serial version ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17652439/8981474).  I have followed the directions in that question, but I have no missing path files and still get the same error. In addition, I **must** use a randomly generated serialVersionUID (even though it is generally [ok to use just 1L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30717112/8981474)) because it is a requirement of my project.

## Problem

Since my eclipse is being uncooperative, I am trying a command line solution.  The command I found, [serialver](https://www.mankier.com/1/serialver), does not generate a serialVersionUID.  According to [How to generate SerialVersionUID](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-generate-serialversionuid/) serialver should generate a serialVersionUID within the file:

> 1. serialver command
>
> JDK has a build in command called “serialver” to generate the
> serialVersionUID automatically. In this example, you use “serialver”
> to generate a serialVersionUID for Address class.
>
> ```
>  E:\workspace\target\classes>serialver Address Address:    static final
>     long serialVersionUID = -687991492884005033L;
> ```

However, I ran this command on one of my classes inside the class' directory and the terminal returned this error:

```
Class Classname.java not found.
```

This error was given regardless if I typed in `serialver Classname` or `serialver Classname.java` into the terminal. I also ran it in the same directory as the files and the error persisted.

## Question

How do I use `serialver` in Linux command line, to set the serialVersionUID of a Java file?  If `serialver` is not the command I should be using, which command (or series of commands) is the proper method?

## Clarification

I want to have a generated and assigned serialVerionUID in my file **from the command line**, therefore the programmatic approach of [How to generate serialVersionUID programmatically in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294326/how-to-generate-serialversionuid-programmatically-in-java) is not what I am looking for. In other words, I want the command to generate this bit of code at the top of my file:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = <some random long>;
```

Comment: how to generate link was useful, especially for Intellij IDEA approach. Thought I'd mention it for others that come across this question but don't want to use the command line approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to specify `-classpath` for the directory that contains your compiled classes (e.g. `bin`). To refer to a class you must use its fully qualified name, including the package -- e.g. for an arraylist class

```
serialver -classpath bin java.util.ArrayList
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `serialver` in the directory containing the compiled .class file, and to specify the classname without extension (Classname, not Classname.java).

Comment: This doesn't work for me .